# Как сделать чтобы фотка сохранялась в storage/upload когда пользователь вставил фото?

Tags: php, laravel

***сама форма***

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="spravka035" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Фото справки по форме 035-1/у') }}</label>
                            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="file" name="image">

                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0" >
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="reg_form">
                                    {{ __('Зарегистрироваться')}}
                                </button>
```

***контроллер если нужен***

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request ->file('image')->store('upload', 'public');



    }
```

> мне нужно чтобы когда пользователь нажимал на (выберите файл)после
>   того как он выберит этот файл сохранялся в storage/uploads после того
>   как пользователь нажмет на кнопку зарегистрироваться .
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала нужно дать доступ к storage :
console: `php artisan storage:link`

А дальше работаем в контроллере:

```
if($request->file('image')) {
        $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/upload/');
    }
```

path - это переменная, которая хранит путь к картинке. Ее можно использовать для БД